# How to change find method for a string?

Tags: javascript

How can i replace find method. It is used incorrectly. IE don't see var mail.

```
var mail = textObj.products.find(function ( itm ) { return itm.name == c }).mail
```

Comment: @Tushar version doesn't matter: `find` is unavailable in all IE versions.

Comment: @Jordumus I mean which IE version should support it

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.find()` is not yet supported in IE and Opera ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)).

If you want to use it, you should insert the Polyfill function for it:

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Array.prototype.filter()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , which is available in IE9 (and up).

Answer (score 1):

This is [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and is not supported by every browser. You should use `filter` instead:

```
textObj.products.filter(function ( itm ) { return itm.name == c })[0].mail
```

Comment: Important to note: `filter` is not available in IE 8 or below.